# Get all WI changed in an organization Using the REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to write a Powershell script that gets all the work items that have changed in an organization after a certain Date time. I only need certain fields but right now just trying to grab all of them and dump them into a CSV. I have tried several APIs but I have been unable to get where I want to go. The Wiql api fails when there are more that 2000 items. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
   #$uri = "$baseurl/$($_.name)/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true"
   #$uri = "$baseurl/$($_.name)/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true&startDateTime=$LastRunTime&Types=$WorkItemType"
   #$uri = "$baseurl/$($_.name)/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.0"
   #TESTING REMOVE
   $uri = "$baseurl/TestingWillBeDeleted/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a design limitation while pulling the workitems without any filters or conditions attached. As per the design, one can pull only 2000 work items at once. If you are looking to pull more than that I would like to recommend you build the Powershell script to

Step 1. Get the list of unique work item types that got altered between choose dates.

Step 2. Customize Powershell to pull the work item of individual type to each sheet in the EXCEL.

for eg: If there are changes on BUG, TASK, USER STORY work items, at the end of step 2 you can see the excel sheet with 3 sheets with individual work items dumped.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this helps , the script will only be pulling one work item type but I could still have more than 2000 changes I am wondering if using the reporting Api and batching would be the better way to go. Sending to Excel is my POC next will be sending to another API.